# How to pass Object as constructor arguments to a contract when using forge create

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment, foundry, forge

Simple deployment command of a contract with two constructor arguments using `forge` is as follows
`forge create src/Contract.sol:MyToken --constructor-args "My Token" "MT"`

But in my case, I should pass some objects as constructor arguments to deploy a contract similar to below one

```
struct DiamondArgs {
    address owner;
    address init;
    bytes initCalldata;
}

contract MyContract {
    constructor(DiamondArgs memory _args) {}
}
```

So, the deployment command would look like this
`forge create src/MyContract.sol:MyContract --constructor-args '{owner: "ownerAddress", init: "initAddress", initCalldata: "initCalldata"}'`

When trying to pass that object, the result looks like this :
`forge create --constructor-args [object Object] ...`

What's the workaround for this?

Comment: Why is your struct DiamondArgs declared outside of your contract?

Comment: It's a global variable, will also be used in inherited contracts, not only in MyContract contract

Comment: Here is a final answer to this issue with the reference of @OlivierD's answer.
When using `--constructor-args`, the deployment command would look something like this.
`forge create src/MyContract.sol:MyContract --constructor-args '(0xMyAddress1,0xMyAddress2,0x03)'`

When using `--constructor-args-path`,
`forge create src/MyContract.sol:MyContract --constructor-args-path args`
And in the arg file(with no extension), the content is as follows
`(0xMyAddress1,0xMyAddress2,0x03)`

Please be careful not to add whitespace between arguments

Comment: This has been tested in [this repo](https://github.com/sunny0714/periphery-contracts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, took me too long to figure it out but you can pass objects by using --constructor-args-path and creating a file named 'args' with your arguments in it.

In your case:

```
(0xMyAddress1, 0xMyAddress2, 0x03)
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have questions!

Comment: Thanks a lot @OlivierD. but how does the _args_ file look like? _args.json_?
I've tried `--constructor-args-path` in a few ways, but still no hope

Comment: I create a file ‘args’. No .txt, .json, .whatever. Just ‘args’. In it, with vscode, I wrote “(0xMyAddress1, 0xMyAddress2, 0x03)“ and it worked

Comment: Not working on my side, Could you check [this repo](https://github.com/sunny0714/periphery-contracts) and test?

Comment: Just cloned your repo. So, first, remove the " around the parentheses of (0x9F79941335e54A11eCD13cedf58375657FdA97A1, 0x9F79941335e54A11eCD13cedf58375657FdA97A1). Second, change those addresses. Didn't work for me when I tried with those 2 addresses so replaced it with my metamask address and it worked on the first try. Don't know if it's a checksum issue or what... Let me know if this works and mark my answer as valid and upvote if it helped you! Thanks

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your detailed explanation, but seems it's not related checksum issue, I guess. That worked with original addresses on my side, though in case of ContractV1.
I have updated the repo with 2 contracts, it will be more understandable for what I'v faced

Comment: When trying with `forge create --rpc-url https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_goerli src/ContractV1.sol:ContractV1 --private-key YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY --constructor-args-path contractV1-args`, it worked well. 
But in case of ContractV2, it didn't work with the error message _Failed to parse tokens_